# How to Parse below XML using java?

Tags: java, json

**Iam trying to get Status and message tag info** using java 1.7

Please any guide me ,
Thanks in advance

```
<API version="0.0">
  <response>
    <operation name="ADD">
      <result>
        <statuscode>200</statuscode>
        <status>Success</status>
        <message> successfully</message>
      </result>
      <Details type="ADD"/>
    </operation>
  </response>
</API>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not how stackoverflow works. You are not even asking a question here.

Comment: thanks @EmreAcar i will rectify my mistake

Comment: First, you should realize that what you posted in not JSON at all. It is XML with a missing header.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a JSON response that you are getting, it's an XML response,
you just need to convert the XML response to POJO class and use the POJO class instead.

Here is how the POJO class will look like

```
public class MyPojo{

    private API API;

    public API getAPI() {
        return API;
    }

    public void setAPI(API API) {
        this.API = API;
    }
}
```

now MyPojo will contain another class named API

```
public class API {

    private Response response;
    private String version;

    public Response getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(Response response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

now the API class contains another class called Response

```
public class Response {

    private Operation operation;

    public Operation getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    public void setOperation(Operation operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }
}
```

Now the Response class is containing another class called Operation

```
public class Operation {

    private Result result;
    private Details Details;
    private String name;

    public Result getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(Result result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public Details getDetails() {
        return Details;
    }

    public void setDetails(Details Details) {
        this.Details = Details;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now you guessed it the Operation class is containing two classes Details and Result

Here is the Result class that is containing the status and message you want to access

```
public class Result {

    private String message;
    private String status;
    private int statuscode;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getStatuscode() {
        return statuscode;
    }

    public void setStatuscode(int statuscode) {
        this.statuscode = statuscode;
    }
}
```

Here is the Details class

```
public class Details {

    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

finally, you can access the status and message by creating an object from MyPojo class like this:

```
String message = myPojo.getAPI().getResponse().getOperation().getResult().getMessage();

String status = myPojo.getAPI().getResponse().getOperation().getResult().getStatus();
```

you can use [this](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/) online converter to convert XML/JSON to POJO.

I hope my answer was helpful :)